# Fixed element with writing-mode being cutoff on iOS devices

Tags: css, ios

I have a small div that stays fixed on the page to show some information but on iOS it gets cut off from the side. I've narrowed the problem down to `writing-mode: vertical-rl` but not sure how to fix it *properly*. Here's a fiddle that you can view on an iOS device

https://jsfiddle.net/nbad7x3s/

HTML:

```
  <div id="metal-prices" class="exp">
    <div class="gold">
      <div class="handle">Gold: $1000</div>
    </div>
    <div class="silver">
      <div class="handle">Silver: $400</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#metal-prices{
    position: fixed;
    right: -10.6rem;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#metal-prices.exp{
    right: 0;
}
#metal-prices .gold,
#metal-prices .silver{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#metal-prices .handle{
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- try `display: table` instead of `display: flex`

Comment: Didn't work. Did you tested it in the jsfiddle?